# Check the continuity at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^3 \cos\frac{1}{y}+y^3 \cos\frac{1}{x}}{x^2+y^2}, & x,y \neq (0,0)\\
0 , &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now i write

$|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| = |\frac{x^3 \cos\frac{1}{y}+y^3 \cos\frac{1}{x}}{x^2+y^2}| < \frac {|x^3| + |y^3|}{x^2+y^2}$ . How should i proceed now ?

Comment: Your function should be defined for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$\frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{|x|^3}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{|x|^3}{x^2}+\frac{|y|^3}{y^2}=|x|+|y|$$

Comment: can we use polar corodinates to solve this

Comment: @Gathdi Sure, you have $\frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}=r(|\cos^3\theta|+|\sin^3\theta|)\leq 2r$.

Comment: so we can say that r goes to 0 so the approximation goes to 0 and f is cts at origin ..is that right ?

Comment: @Gathdi Yes, what you are saying is $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}f(x,y)=\lim_{r\to 0}f(x,y)=0=f(0,0)$. So $f$ is continuous at the origin.